# set of all regular values

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $f: M\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth. Show that the set of all regular values of $f$ is open.

How can I prove it? Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proving that the set of regular values of $f$ is open is equivalent to proving that the set of critical values is closed.  The set $S$ of critical points of $f$ is closed. (One way to show this is to show that the set of regular points is open.  This can be done using a local parameterization.)  Since $X$ is compact, this means that $S$ is compact.  By continuity, $f(S)$, which equals the set of critical values of $f$, is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and therefore closed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand in case $f: M\longrightarrow N$, which $N$ has dimension less then $M$, the set of all regular points of $f$ is open in $M$?? I.e, I can't not prove, for example $f: \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ has $Df(x)$ is surjective at $x$ then $Df(z)$ is also surjective at a neighborhood of $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Well it suffices to look locally, i.e. chart by chart. Inside $\mathbb{R}^n$, you're interested in where $df$ is not identically zero, i.e. the locus $\cup_{i=1}^n \{ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \neq 0 \}$, which is open.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: Okay: you can have an open cover of $M$ by copies $U_i$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and you can check that a set $W$ is open iff $W \cap U_i$ for all $i$ - this is just point set topology. With that, you're reduced to answering the question for $\mathbb{R}^n$ - you want say that if $x$ is not a critical value, nearby guys are not either. What does it mean to be critical? All your partials vanish. So at $x$, some $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \neq 0$, by continuity this is true nearby.

Comment: May it also true incase replace $\mathbb{R}$ by a manifold $N$? where $dim M > dim N$ ?

Comment: Yes, you're welcome. Now use that at $x$, some $\dim N$ minor of the Jacobian has nonvanishing determinant (this works for $\geqslant$ as well).

Comment: Sorry for disturb you, but I have just study this subject, so If you have time, I hope you can write for me more detail?, I can not imagine well about it.

Comment: As before it suffices to check on a cover: now take a cover $U_i$ for $N$ with each $U_i \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$, and take a cover $V_{ij}$ for $f^{-1}(U_i)$ with each $V_{ij} \simeq \mathbb{R}^m$, with this it suffices to check that for a map $\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the noncritical locus is open. At a point in it $x$, the Jacobian matrix $df$ has full rank - it is a linear algebra exercise that this means some $\dim N$ minor of it has full rank - since this minor's determinant is continuous as a function on $\mathbb{R}^m$, it is still nonzero nearby, so still $df$ is full rank.

Comment: oh thank you very much :) I will try,

Comment: @uncookedfalcon, forgive me if I’m wrong, but I think that a regular value is a point $y \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $df$ doesn’t vanish at any point in $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, whereas a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ so that $df_x$ is not zero is called a regular point.  At least, these are the definitions that I learned from my differential topology text (Guillemin and Pollack).

Comment: @SarahT. you are absolutely right, I was being careless. Good catch!